# Authorizing Nova using Laravel Policy

Tags: laravel, laravel-nova

I am currently using Nova for my back office app and trying to grant users authentication based on their role. I have written a couple of policies which all work except one. I have gone through it over and over again to see if I am missing out something but I haven't been able to find anything. I need you guys to help have a second look to help me figure out what I am doing wrong. Here's the code I am working with

**Order policy**

```
<?php

namespace App\Policies;

use App\Models\Order;
use App\User;
use Illuminate\Auth\Access\HandlesAuthorization;

class OrderPolicy
{
    use HandlesAuthorization;

    /**
     * Determine whether the user can view any order.
     *
     * @param  \App\User  $user
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function viewAny(User $user)
    {
        return $user->hasAnyRole(['crm']);
    }
}
```

**Order nova resource**

```
class Order extends Resource
{
    public static function indexQuery(NovaRequest $request, $query)
    {
        return $query->where('status_id', 'paid');
    }

    public static $model = 'App\Models\Order';

    public static $title = 'id';

    public static $search = [
        'id', 'reference'
    ];

    public function fields(Request $request)
    {
        return [
            // fields that should be displayed
        ];
    }

   // other functions
}
```

**AuthServiceProvider**

```
class AuthServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * The policy mappings for the application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $policies = [
        // other policies
        'App\Models\Order' => 'App\Policies\OrderPolicy',
    ];

    public function boot()
    {
        $this->registerPolicies();

        // ....
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong with this policy?

Comment: What exactly not working ? User able to view or not view, can you please explain more

Comment: So users with a different role are still able to view the resource.

Answer (score -1):

The viewAny method, for Nova, nearly always has to return true. In your example, unless a user has the role "crm", then they will not be able to view the Order resource.

Many believe, myself included, that this is counter-intuitive. For example, you may want all users to be able to see the Order resource, but only able to see their Orders. This isn't possible in Laravel Nova without significant over riding. To filter the what Orders the users can see, you need to override the indexQuery (Which you appear to have done)

This issue on Github may help explain it: https://github.com/laravel/nova-issues/issues/1762

Comment: no thats not true, viewAny method by default return true but you can change it according to your authorization logic. viewAny hides the whole resource.
reference: https://nova.laravel.com/docs/resources/authorization.html#hiding-entire-resources